# Javascript SetInterval timing issue, total time

Tags: javascript, events

```
base ={time:0};    
var loop = 0;
 setInterval(function(){
    if(base.time === 9000){
        move();
       base.time = 0;
     }

  base.time ++;                      

},1);
```

Shouldn't the move(); function occur every 9s? I timed it and its much less, why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setInterval` will not run every millisecond.  There is a minimum possible interval that is longer than that.

If you want something to run in nine seconds, you should use `setTimeout()` for 9 seconds.  Plus your code doesn't reset base.time back to zero so it would only match 9000 once anyway.

If you want it to run every 9 seconds, then you can use `setInterval(handler, 9000)` or you can use `setTimeout(handler, 9000)` and then set the next `setTimeout` in your handler function.

This will execute `move()` every nine seconds:

```
var intervalTimer = setInterval(function(){
    move();
}, 9000);
```

Here's a useful article on the topic: http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/Minimum-Timer-Intervals-in-JavaScript.

To reset the time back to 9 seconds when a button is clicked use this code:

```
var intervalTimer;

function startTimer() {
    intervalTimer = setInterval(function(){
        move();
    }, 9000);
}

function handleClick() {
    clearInterval(intervalTimer);   // stop currently running interval
    startTimer();
}

startTimer();
```

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/sF2by/.

Comment: I agree with this, but it still makes me wonder why he asks why it runs *faster* than he expects, and not *slower*.

Comment: I would do setInterval with 9000 however if the user clicks an element it resets the base.time. How would you write the function with setTimeout for an infinite loop?

Comment: @Pointy, I actually think "much less" in the OP refers to amount of calls rather than time between calls. It's the only thing that makes sense, unless the original code behaves differently.

Answer (score 0):

Intervals are easy as pie!

```
var move = function(){
    alert("move!");
};

setInterval(move, 9000);
```

[See it work here on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bmRUy/)

Answer (score 0):

You can't count on `setInterval` actually running every 1 ms. If the CPU is used for another process, it might not run for 1 *second*. Instead, use one of the following:

```
function move() {
    // Do stuff.
}

// The obvious solution.
// Certain browsers (Chrome) may put the script in "inactive" mode which will
// pause setInterval code. This means move will be run too few times, if you
// actually depend on it being called X times for Y time.
setInterval(move, 9000);

// The other solution.
// Get the delta between each loop and run the move loop as necessary.
// WARNING: This is not efficient, and you should only use this if you have a
//          good reason to do so.
// EXTRA WARNING: This code is actually retarded in its current form. It's just
//                here to show you how you'd do it. Since you didn't post your
//                original problem, it's hard to know what you're really after.
var time = +new Date, frequency = 9000;
setInterval(function () {
    var dt = new Date - time;
    // Check if we've waited long enough.
    if (dt >= frequency) {
        // If the process hangs for 20 seconds, this value would be 2. Usually,
        // it will be 1.
        // Also, Chrome will pause interval counters, so if a tab is inactive,
        // this count could be really high when the tab gets focus again.
        var times = Math.floor(dt / frequency);
        console.log('Moving', times, 'time(s)!');
        for (var i = 0; i < times; i++) {
            move();
        }
        // Start counting time from the last update.
        time += times * frequency;
    }
}, 1); // 1 could probably be much higher here. Depends on your use case.
```

Answer (score 0):

You wrote in a comment that there is a button which resets the time, and that's why you don't want to just setTimeout for the full delay. Here's how to handle that:

```
var running;
function start() {
    clearInterval(running);
    running = clearInterval(function () {
        move();
    }, 9000);
}
```

Every time start() is called, the time will be reset to 9 seconds from now, and if 9 seconds elapse, move() will be called and another 9-second interval will start. If you don't actually want it to happen repeatedly, just use setTimeout instead.

The key is using clearInterval (or clearTimeout) to cancel your previous 9-second-delay and start a new one. It is harmless to call clearInterval with a junk value.